# Constantly constrain element to the top of a beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, formatting, frame-title

<strike>For a presentation, I</strike> Some really helpful users here helped me to create what is basically a chevron-based progress bar. This is a substitute of a frame title in my presentation.

However, depending on the other content on the slide, the progress-bar moves vertically. Is there a way to constantly constrain it to the top margin of the slide (much like a frame title would)? I have tried wrapping this inside the frame title, but that way, there is a lot of spacing added.

[image] [image]

<sup>The vertical difference is arguably very small, but even more annoying to the eye that way. The most extreme case would - obviously - be an empty slide, where the progress-bar is centred in the middle.</sup>

MWE below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{svg}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

%\sisetup {
    %locale = DE,
    %per-mode = symbol
%}

% THEME AND COLOR SETUP
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{
    \glqq#1\grqq
}
\date{03. Juli 2018}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tikzset{start/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30,
        text width=16mm, text=black, minimum height=23mm, font=\tiny,
        signal pointer angle=150, on chain},
    cont/.style = {start=#1, signal from=west, text=black}
}


\mode<presentation>{}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
     \begin{center}
        \setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}
        \begin{figure}[T]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm,
        start chain = going right,
        mylabel/.style={anchor=north west,font=\bfseries\tiny, color=black}
        ]

        \node[start=darkred!80!black, label={[mylabel]north west:Meldebogen}] {
            \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\color{black}{einziger Anhaltspunkt f\"{u}r Verfahren}}
            \item \"{U}berpr\"{u}fung der Angaben schwer                       
            \end{itemize}   
        };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Anklage}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Beweisaufnahme}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Urteil}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Revision}] {};      
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \end{center}
            \vspace{5mm}
            \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
                 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Entnazifizierung_Bilder/Zwissler_Meldebogen_Fehler.jpg}
             \end{column}
             \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
                 \emph{F\"{u}r den Fall, dass in dieser Spalte (\ldots) der Eintritt in die Partei einzusetzen war, (\ldots), bitte (ich), gegebenenfalls meinen abgegebenen Meldebogen entsprechend zu berichtigen}
          \end{column}
      \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t, fragile]
    \begin{center}
        \setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}
        \begin{figure}[T]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm,
        start chain = going right,
        mylabel/.style={anchor=north west,font=\bfseries\tiny, color=black}
        ]

        \node[start=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Meldebogen}] {
            \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\color{black}{einziger Anhaltspunkt f\"{u}r Verfahren}}
            \item \"{U}berpr\"{u}fung der Angaben schwer                       
            \end{itemize}   
        };
        \node[cont=darkred!80!black, label={[mylabel]north west:Anklage}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Beweisaufnahme}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Urteil}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Revision}] {};      
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \end{center}
    \begin{columns}
                \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
                    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
                        \item \"{O}ffentliche Kl\"{a}ger erhebt Anklage in Ludwigsburg
                \end{itemize} 
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight]{Entnazifizierung_Bilder/Schick_Meldebogen_01.jpg}\\
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Just for reference, some failed attempts:

[image]
[image]

<sup>left: simply wrapping everything in `\frametitle{}`; right: trying `\begin{centred}[T]`</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second frame, you already picked the correct option: `[t]`. However, the fact that you put the `tikzpicture` in a figure makes things unnecessarily complicated <s>as figures are floats, which, errr, float</s>. (Big thanks to @samcarter for clarification.) Here comes a proposal that (I believe) won't jump.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{svg}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{
    \glqq#1\grqq
}
\date{03. Juli 2018}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tikzset{start/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30,
        text width=16mm, text=black, minimum height=23mm, font=\tiny,
        signal pointer angle=150, on chain},
    cont/.style = {start=#1, signal from=west, text=black}
}


\mode<presentation>{}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[t]
\vspace*{-1mm}\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2mm,
        start chain = going right,
        mylabel/.style={anchor=north west,font=\bfseries\tiny, color=black}
        ]
        \setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}
        \node[start=darkred!80!black, label={[mylabel]north west:Meldebogen}] {
            \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\color{black}{einziger Anhaltspunkt f\"{u}r Verfahren}}
            \item \"{U}berpr\"{u}fung der Angaben schwer                       
            \end{itemize}   
        };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Anklage}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Beweisaufnahme}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Urteil}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Revision}] {};      
        \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{column}               
\end{columns}
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
     \emph{F\"{u}r den Fall, dass in dieser Spalte (\ldots) der Eintritt in die Partei einzusetzen war, (\ldots), bitte (ich), gegebenenfalls meinen abgegebenen Meldebogen entsprechend zu berichtigen}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t, fragile]
\vspace*{-1mm}\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{\textwidth}
\centering
        \setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm,
        start chain = going right,
        mylabel/.style={anchor=north west,font=\bfseries\tiny, color=black}
        ]

        \node[start=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Meldebogen}] {
            \begin{itemize} 
            \item {\color{black}{einziger Anhaltspunkt f\"{u}r Verfahren}}
            \item \"{U}berpr\"{u}fung der Angaben schwer                       
            \end{itemize}   
        };
        \node[cont=darkred!80!black, label={[mylabel]north west:Anklage}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Beweisaufnahme}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Urteil}] {};
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Revision}] {};      
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}               
\end{columns}
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
     \begin{itemize}[<+->]
         \item \"{O}ffentliche Kl\"{a}ger erhebt Anklage in Ludwigsburg
 \end{itemize} 
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight]{example-image}\\
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EXPLANATION**: What went wrong in my previous answer? When moving things around, I moved

```
        \setlength{\leftmargini}{6pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1pt}
```

outside the `tikzpicture`, these settings became global and messed up things. Sorry about that!

Comment: p.1 looks great and so does the top of page 2, but what happened with all the margins? The `itemize` is far-left, and the image touching the picture. Is this because of overlay (i.e. on a full slide, the top bar would just be above everything else)?

Comment: @Narusan (Again) my bad, I moved some options outside the tikzpicture, will fix it.

Comment: +1, however figures are no floats in beamer, they are basically just a `center` environment (which adds unnecessary space, so the conclusion is correct).

Comment: @marmot You're welcome! Great answer!

Comment: In the second slide, there appears to be a margin missing.It can be fixed easily with `\vspace{5mm}`, but it's somewhat weird that this margin is apparently included in the first slide.

Comment: @Narusan Absolutely. Again my bad. Was distracted in a chat ;-)